# Tabulator header row height not proper after filter toggle

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I'm using reactified Tabulator. Great component, thanks to Oli.

I need a simple 'toggle' feature for the filtering functionality on the headers. This is easy to do with the documentation help. The header row becomes wider when the filters are enabled, of course. Now, when I disable the filters, the header height remains. I have even tried to redraw() the full table, but no luck.

Tabulator version 4.6. Some screenshots below.

Before filters are enabled, perfect height[image]

After enabling filters, the height is wider as expected[image]

Disabling filters now, the height is still wider than it should be[image]

Comment: You're going to say the height became wider?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked (workaround): Instead of using the `updateColumnDefinition` method, I used the `setColumns` method. This does the right thing and resizes the header row after it is set.

Both are documented here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/columns#replace

Also, the `updateColumnDefinition` is very slow if you are calling it for each column (I tried on a table with 44 columns and it takes 15+ seconds if I update the columns in a loop). Better is to set everything once and call the `setColumns` method.